# Downloading csv files from different server

Tags: java, javascript, php, csv

I can't think of any way doing this but am still a bit curious whether there is some hack. So here's the scenario:

- There is my Server X and different Server Y. Server Y generates various reports depending upon the input parameters, my Server X parses them and makes them available for download.
- So to perform this I have access to JSON API of Server Y, and I can easily do using PHP Curl on my Server X, but I want to move this load to client side instead of having the load on my Server X. Since each file download takes roughly 1 to 2 seconds (size around 2–3MB and its CSV file), and every user might have around 100–200 such files to download, this can make my server X crash I think if there are around 20 users approximately.

So I want to move this load of downloading csv from different server onto client side. I have tried with applets they won't work due to same cross origin policy. And javascript I can't think of any way of downloading them, since there isn't any option available for cross domain issue. So I am open to anything like a chrome extension or any such thing which can do this job without involving my server in it.

Also please let me know if my assumption of crashing of server is incorrect; I am not sure because network calls will be considered I/O and how many threads the NIC card can support.

**EDIT**

I want my web application to be able to download files by itself from Server Y without involving my Server X. That is, my web client should be able to download things directly from a third-party server without involving my server.

Comment: In any way your server Y should provide a file to download and build report on the client side. What kind of load you want to remove from server Y? Report generation functionality ?

Comment: Not from Server Y, I don't want to remove any load from server Y, I want that my server X should not interfere in the download, since user logs into my server not Y

Comment: Rafael, i have update the question description, I think it was bit confusing previously. Thanks

Comment: Instead of saying 1-2 seconds, I'd rather know the size of the files.  1-2 seconds? The files must be huge.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. You want to generate a file (what is the file format? binary?) on the server Y and provide it directly to the client without using server X. And client should parse this file and build report. Am I right?

Comment: exactly, and server Y is already doing this task and I don't have any control on it

Comment: As a former designer of NIC cards for IBM; FYI:  NIC cards are not multi-treaded.  It is a single serial stream of data.  Not multiple streams.

Comment: misunderstood, i have update the file size in the question. And I thought in the same way for the NIC cards, thats why I don't want the file download load on server

Comment: @codeomnitrix in this case consider javascript libraries for csv visualization. For instance: http://economistry.com/2013/07/easy-data-visualization-with-google-charts-and-a-csv/

Comment: @codeomnitrix to decrease the load on the server Y also consider file caching, to avoid file generation, if this file already generated before.

Comment: Rafael, that is fine but how can my client download files from other server(Cross origin policy), I don't have any issues parsing them I got a couple of libraries to do that.

Comment: I think there has been a confusion. I don't bother about server Y, it can serve as many requests as I want. For me its like blackbox. I want no load on my Server X so want to do it file download with client side scripts instead of involving my server X.

Comment: @codeomnitrix can you redirect a client request to the server Y from server X?

Comment: I am using curl not redirection, Server X acts as web proxy

Comment: Please don't do this, the place for this work to be done is on the server, moving this to the client is nuts.  Improve the code so it is more efficient on the server.

Comment: croos origin issues can be avoided configuring server Y to allow it http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Answer (score 0):

Is it CSV or JSON?

Not important, either way you have a serious issue to resolve.

I will assume that the API request will often be the same down load.

I suggest that when an API request is made that the response be returned to the user, then saved locally.

Use PHP to get the CSV (or JSON) data which eliminates the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing issues.

When you save the CSV locally you need to give it a unique file name which includes the parameters.  The number of characters in a file name is cheap.

Before you make an API request, first use

```
if(file_exists($filename))
```

File naming convention, use the same parameters form the API request to name the file.

```
$param['parm1name'] = 'param1';
$param['parm2name'] = 'param2';
$param['parm3name'] = 'param3';
$param['parm4name'] = 'param4';
$param['parm5name'] = 'param5';
$filename = '';
$query = '?';
foreach ($param as $key => $value){
  $filename .= $value;
  $query .= "$key=$value&";
}
$filename .= '.csv';
if (file_exists($filename)){
  header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');  
  readfile($filename)
else{
   $query = substr($query,0,-1);  // remove trailing "&"
  // do API request and return data to user
  $fp = fopen($filename,'w');
  fwrite($fp,$data);
  fclose($fp);
}
```